# php table array direction

Tags: php, arrays

```
<div class="section" id="section2">
<div class="slide" id="slide1">
<div class="box">
  <div class="haha1">Library</div>
 <p>
<table class="box1" width="700" border="1">

<?php 

    $cnt= 0;
    $nThumbXRow =5 ;
    $sql = ("SELECT * FROM bookstore");
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row =mysql_fetch_array($result)){

        if ($cnt%$nThumbXRow == 0){
            echo "<tr>";
        }
         echo "<td><img src='" . $row['image'] . 
               "' height='250' width='150'><br />" .  
               $row['bookname'] ."<br />" .  
                $row['author'] . 
                " <br /><input type='submit' name='add'
                    value='Add Cart'></td>";
        $cnt++;
        if ($cnt%$nThumbXRow == 0){
            echo "</tr><!-- row ending here -->";
         }

      }
     ?>     
</table>

<br>
<center>Page 1</center>
    </div></div>




<?php   

$sql = ("SELECT * FROM bookstore");
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row =mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
?>

<table class="box1" width="700" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td><img src="<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" height="250" width="150"><br>
      <?php echo $row['bookname']; ?><br>
      <?php echo $row['author']; ?><br>
      <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add Cart"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<?php } ?>
```

This is my table when I add new item list down vertically but I want array item horizontally example [item1,item2,item3,item4] after array 4 item horizontally only create another `td` then array again horizontally 4 time.

**Required output:**

```
{1,2,3,4}
{5,6,7,8}
```

array from left to right

else array vertically {1,5} {2,6},{3,7],[4,8]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try change the table this way

```
<table class="box1" width="700" border="1">

<?php 
        $cnt= 0;
        $nThumbXRow =5 ;
        $sql = ("SELECT * FROM bookstore");
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        while($row =mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            if ($cnt%$nThumbXRow == 0){
                echo "<tr>";
            }
             echo "<td><img src='" . $row['image'] . 
                   "' height='250' width='150'><br />" .  
                   $row['bookname'] ."<br />" .  
                    $row['author'] . 
                    " <br /><input type='submit' name='add'
                        value='Add Cart'></td>";
            $cnt++;
            if ($cnt%$nThumbXRow == 0){
                echo "</tr><!-- row ending here -->";
            }

        }
    ?>     
</table>
```

for testing the echo try a simple case like this (only the button)

```
echo "<td><input type='submit' name='add'
                    value='Add Cart'></td>";
```

In this sample (I have not you db an your IMG so i have change the var value with string value you can see 2 row of pic 4 in the first and 2 in the second.

Then if you don'obtain the same result could be you have some problem with your select or your value..

```
<table class="box1" width="700" border="1">

<?php 

    $cnt= 0;
    $nThumbXRow =4 ;
    $book = 0;
/*    $sql = ("SELECT * FROM bookstore");
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row =mysql_fetch_array($result)){*/
    while( $book<=5 ){
        if ($cnt%$nThumbXRow == 0){
            echo "<tr>";
        }
/*         echo "<td><img src='" . $row['image'] . 
               "' height='250' width='150'><br />" .  
               $row['bookname'] ."<br />" .  
                $row['author'] . 
                " <br /><input type='submit' name='add'
                    value='Add Cart'></td>";*/
            echo  "<td><img src='" . "row['image']" . 
               "' height='250' width='150'><br />" ."row['bookname']<br />" .  "row['author']<br />" .  "<input type='submit' name='add'
                    value='Add Cart'></td>";
        $cnt++;

        if ($cnt%$nThumbXRow == 0){
            echo "</tr><!-- row ending here -->";
         }
        $book++;

      }
?>     
</table>
```

Comment: after changed there is no output display

Comment: I have forgot the single quote in src= '  .. try again

Comment: still the same bro. no output

Comment: output Same agian  , just can saw the table border line only

Comment: i remove the select outside the table and add your select inside , it works but align vertically and no image display just a thumb nail

Comment: is there no function in the variable $cnt= 0; and  $nThumbXRow = 4; ?

Comment: Well begin to work.  This mean the qeustion you have posted is solved. In this case is fair mark as accepetd and or rate as useful.  The vars are variable for controlling the insertion of the td tag.. One count the image and one if for check when change row.   The align should controlled by a css related to your img or inlline.. and for the thumbnail, is related to the different image?, is the image but smaller)

Comment: i edited my question i wan the output like that , how to control by css to array them ? not php formula ?

Comment: Is not fair change the question when you have already obtained a correct answer

Comment: how to array them horizontally in css??

Comment: But how many img you use for test? and can you see me the actual result? I can not imagine what you see...

Comment: i use 5 image to test , they array vertically in table , never create another column . i wan the output only max 2 row.

Comment: There was several error (cnt vwithout $ and a wrong position of increment $cnt++.(implies 5 not more 4 for check) . try now please.. should show the 4 img  x row

Comment: still same output ( 1 column align vertically), the table item is , when i add new book ,it will appear in table with image,bookname and author  . Not depend on how many image i used .

Comment: Coulbe the problem is in the echo. try like suggest in the answer i have updated..(only button for now)

Comment: after change , 1 vertical list down button . i want array from left to right , not top to bottom

Comment: Ok . 
Me leaving 4 on the same line and one on the next line, I make another control

Comment: Please add your actual code to the question,  (leave  the originale adn at the bottom add the actual) so i can see what code you are using now,

Comment: mean in my test i show 4 in the same row and one in the next

Comment: how to set if i wan max for only 2 row

Comment: I have added a "static " sample for test the work. and for the limit to 2 row you can change the while condition..

Comment: problem solve , tq , now another problem my image is all Garbage characters.

Comment: If the problem is solved i'm happy... for the new problem is better if you post a new properly explained question,  this allow to all SO comunity  see your post...

Comment: how actually use the while book to set maximum only 8 column if exceed will start a new page in next section to add in.

Comment: If you use bootstrap like did in the sample 8 column is not the best because twitter grid is base non 12 column and 8 is not an integer devider.  I suggest you 6 column or 12 column. Anyway you can change the value of  $nThumbXRow = yourNumberOfColumn